# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\cos(n))}{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was doing some exercises and this one just stunned me.
I had to study the convergence of this serie:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\cos(n))}{n}$$

I tried alot of diffrent things, but I got no where.
Can anyone please help me with an idea or a clue just to start ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What exactly do you want to study in it?

Comment: if it's converge or not

Comment: Are you asking whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(\cos(n))/n$ converges?

Comment: yes exactly, that's what im looking for

Comment: I believe it converges, which follows from the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: your answer doesn't realy help, can u make it more detailed ?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt What do you mean? Are you implying that because the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)^{2k+1}}{n}$ converges and the Taylor Series for $\sin(\cos n)$ will include only odd terms of cosine that we can conclude convergence? I would be careful here, because we have a double summation... even though each term of the Taylor Series converges, that does not mean they converge when all added together. If I understand you right though, that idea could work.

Comment: @HptunjyPrjkeizg Here in math stack exchange we don't simply do homework for you. You should show the steps you used to solve the question. Then others will respond.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yes, the lack of answers below makes it clear I do not feel safe about this.  :-)  But I am heading to bed.  Best of luck if you want to make it work, but it seems quite difficult.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt haha, fair enough. I might take a stab at it tonight or tomorrow if you don't. Sleep well!

Comment: To use Dirichlet's test it would suffice to find a bound $B_k$ for $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N\cos(n)^{2k+1}\right|$ such that $\sum_k B_k/(2k+1)!$ is finite. Each of those sums is bounded (independent of $N$), though they might be quite large when $e^{(2k+1)i}$ is close to $1$.

Comment: this is not a home work i can garentee that, i just found this on internet and wanted to know how to solve it that's all, and thx alot for your help guys !

Comment: Numerically, according to Wolfy, it appears to about 0.0648.

Comment: This is an interesting question and honestly I do not understand the downvotes or the closing votes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio while it was an interesting question, that alone does not determine whether or not a question is of good quality.  (And I also feel like some people downvoted it because the question was too hard, but don't quote me on that)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: of course, that is a matter of personal opinion. Mine is that an interesting question and a good formatting should grant for quality, so I am voting for reopening. Do we really want to be flooded by highly upvoted questions like *prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2 e^n e^{e^n}}$ is convergent* and banish this kind of deeper math?

Comment: some think that it's my home work, it's not true i just found this in another forum i can post it if people think that im just asking them to do my work for me

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio of course I feel the same.  Just guessing at what others think since they'll probably never reveal themselves.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I think this is an interesting problem. I knew that this has some connection to the irrationality measure of $\pi$ and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202138/determine-whether-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-sinnn-converges/2207289#2207289) that I answered. In my answer $O(n^{-1/\mu+\epsilon})$ is used, and it is great to see that a stronger bound $O(n^{-1/(\mu-1)+\epsilon})$ is possible in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternate to Jack D'Aurizio's answer, which interestingly also involves the irrationality measure of $\pi$ (call it $\mu$). Suppose $f$ is a $2\pi$-periodic smooth function, such that $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\;dx=0$. Let
$$
  s_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n f(k).
$$
By the [Koksma–Hlawka inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence#The_Koksma.E2.80.93Hlawka_inequality) and [this bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence#Additive_recurrence),
$$
  |s_n|=O(n^{-1/(\mu-1)+\epsilon})
$$
for any $\epsilon>0$. In particular, choosing $\epsilon<\frac1{2(\mu-1)}$, we have $|s_n|=O(n^{-\epsilon})$. Using summation by parts,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{f(n)}n
    &=&s_N+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}ns_n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\    
    &=&s_N+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{s_n}{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The above implies $s_N\to0$ and the last sum is absolutely convergent, so the LHS converges. In particular setting $f(x)=\sin(\cos(x))$, the series in question converges.

Comment: Thank you ! i really liked your answer, i actually thought about using the summation by part, but from the begining, that's why i got no where with it XD

Answer (score 6):

I think it is more practical to expand $\sin\cos(x)$ as a Fourier cosine series. We have

$$\sin\cos(x) = 2\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m J_{2m+1}(1) \cos((2m+1)x) $$
where the coefficients $J_{2m+1}(1)$, depending on a modified Bessel function of the first kind, have an exponential decay. On the other hand
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=-\log\left|2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|$$
for any $x\not\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, and $-\log\left|2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|$ cannot be too large for some small $x\in\mathbb{N}$ since $\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure. By exploiting the exponential decay of the previous coefficients we may conclude that the original series is convergent.

Comment: you will loose the reader with a Bessel function, simply say $a_m$ decreases fast enough because $\sin \cos x$ is smooth ?

Comment: @user1952009: of course, that and the irrationality measure of $\pi$ are the key ingredients.

Comment: Thank you for reopening this question and providing a great answer!