# Does the series $\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)}{x}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I really have no clue where to start with this one as I am used to having the argument of the trig function be (πx) which makes it easy to treat it like an alternating series.

Comment: You didn't provide a series

Comment: [Apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2239524/6460) $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(kn)}{n}=-\log\left|2\sin\frac{k}{2}\right|$ for $k\not\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ so the answer is presumably *yes* here too

Comment: Again apparently, Wolframalpha can do the summation and the result is $(3+2 \pi)/4 \simeq 2.3208$.  This doesn't tell us though why the series converges and how to arrive at that result.

Comment: It converge by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test). you can verify this by verifying the partials sums of the form $\left|\sum_{x=1}^p \sin\left(\frac32 x\right)\right|$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\frac{\sin(3x/2)}{x}$ is defined at $x=0$ as $\frac{3}{2}$, it is a convergent series by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), since the partial sums of the sequence $\left\{\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}n\right)\right\}_{n\geq 0}$ are bounded. Additionally, [it is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) that the Fourier series
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} $$
is pointwise convergent to the function $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, hence

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}n\right)}{n} = \frac{3}{2}+\frac{\pi-\frac{3}{2}}{2} = \color{red}{\frac{3+2\pi}{4}}.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate quickly why the partial sum of $\sin(\frac32 n)$ is bounded ? :)

Comment: @Zubzub: for short, $\sin(z)=\text{Im}(e^{iz})$, $\text{Im}$ and $\sum$ commute and $\sum_{n=1}^{N}e^{niz}$ can be computed as a geometric series.

Comment: @JackDAurizio Oh yeah of course... !

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

By [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) we have that $1/x$ is a decreasing sequence, going to zero. Then $\sum_{x=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)}{x}$ will converge if $|\sum_{x=0}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)|$ is bounded. However, this is the case. So the answer to the question is "yes".

As for the boundedness:
Let $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N \sin\left(\frac{3n}{2}\right)$. Then
 $$2\sin \left( \frac1{2} \right) \times S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \cos \left( \frac{3(n-1)}{2}\right) - \cos \left( \frac{3(n+1)}{2}\right)\right) \\
= \cos \left( -\frac3{2} \right) + \cos \left( 0 \right) - \cos\left( \frac{3(N)}{2}\right)- \cos\left( \frac{3(N+1)}{2} \right)$$

So for any $N$, $S_N$ is bounded.