# Partial sum of Beatty sequence of $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a fast algorithm to compute the sum of first $n$ terms of the Beatty sequence $e$? That is, I want to compute

$$\lfloor e\rfloor+\lfloor 2e\rfloor+\lfloor 3e\rfloor+\lfloor 4e\rfloor+\lfloor 5e\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor ne\rfloor$$

for very large $n$. Here $n$ can have up to $4000$ digits.

OEIS: http://oeis.org/A184976

Comment: What do you need it for? And have you tried to come up with anything?

Comment: I can't come up with anything fast and computationally feasible.

Comment: Why the ${e \over 2 n^2}$ approximate is not enough?

Comment: Several people has asked this question recently (either as a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2307399/59379) directly or asking in the comment of answer to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2052179/59379)). What is the source of this problem?

Comment: also see [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308258/bounds-on-floor-summation-sumn-k-lfloor-c-cdot-k-rfloor?noredirect=1#comment4752433_2308258) about an approximation.

Comment: @achillehui this problem is from an [ongoing contest](https://www.codechef.com/JUNE17). The OP is cheating. https://www.codechef.com/JUNE17/problems/ES

Comment: @maverick: I have asked the mods to put the question on lockdown, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I'm here anxiously awaiting for the day that you earn mod status and can do this yourself :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve summation $\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor e\cdot i \rfloor $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307399/solve-summation-sum-i-1n-lfloor-e-cdot-i-rfloor)

Answer (score 6):

I think that the most reasonable way for tackling such problem is to exploit the fact that the continued fraction of $e$ is well-known, so they are the convergents of the continued fraction of $e$:
$$ e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1,10,\ldots] \tag{1} $$
$$ \frac{3}{1},\quad \frac{8}{3},\quad \frac{11}{4},\quad \frac{19}{7},\quad \frac{87}{32},\quad \frac{106}{39},\quad \frac{193}{71},\quad \frac{1264}{465},\quad\ldots\tag{2} $$
and the convergent $\frac{p_m}{q_m}$ allows to exactly compute $\left\lfloor e\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor 2 e\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor M e\right\rfloor$ up to $M=q_m$ by just replacing $e$ with its $m$-th convergent.

Anyway, since you should know that every positive integer number can be represented either as $\left\lfloor e a \right\rfloor $ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$ or as $\left\lfloor \frac{e}{e-1}b\right\rfloor$ for some $b\in\mathbb{N}$, the asymptotic behaviour of $\left\lfloor e\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor 2 e\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor n e\right\rfloor$ is pretty clear, and I honestly doubt that you really need to compute such sum exactly. If so, for which purpose?

Comment: Sorry if I missed something. But how do we compute $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor k\dfrac{p}{q}\right\rfloor$ fast?

Comment: It is not difficult to compute the fractional part of a number of the form a/q, it only depends on a mod q, and there is an obvious periodicity in that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You are helping them to solve https://www.codechef.com/JUNE17/problems/ES which is a problem in an ongoing contest.